# Using Webkit, how do I make pages available offline? Obj-C, Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

Alright. So I have an app that loads webpages from Wikipedia.org/WolframAlpha.com. I want to add a button that downloads a page for offline use. How would I go about doing that using Webkit? I don't believe I want pure caching, as I want the page to always be available until the user deletes it (I think I need to download to hard drive or something).

I am not very familiar with Webkit, so any help would be appreciated. At the moment all I have is:

```
- (IBAction)downloadWebpage:(id)sender {
    //Download Webpage
}
```

My webView is defined as `*webView`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLRequest with an NSURLConnection to get the data of the URL, and save it locally on a file. UIWebView has a few methods you can use, such as – loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:, which would allow you to render local data on the web view.

some relevant documentation: [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [UIWebview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, but if you can give some examples that would really be helpful. I am kind of new at Objective-C and Webkit.

Comment: You can start by observing the related sample code of each of these classes. You will be able to find the sample code on the "Related sample code" section of each of these classes's documentation.

Comment: Well, I tried it out, but I still don't really know what to do. How do I download all necessary page so that they are available offline?

Comment: At the moment nothing. I have no idea where to start. There has to be some kind of method I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a bit late.

WebKit has it built-in. The right thing to do is to use WebArchive.
See WebArchive's -data method for more information on this.

The following code is not tested, but it should explain what you need to know.

```
WebFrame      *webFrame = [webView mainFrame];
WebDataSource *dataSource = [webFrame dataSource];
WebArchive    *webArchive = [dataSource webArchive];
NSString      *filename = @"MyTestArchive.webarchive";
NSString      *path = @"~/MyArchives";
NSString      *pathname = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSError       *error = NULL;

pathname = [pathname stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
[[webArchive data] writeToFile:pathname options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error];
```

You can also get the webArchive this way:

```
NSString   *urlString = @"http://www.example.com/";
NSURL      *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
WebArchive *webArchive = [[WebArchive alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

[webArchive autorelease];

... (save [webArchive data] like above)
```

To get a filename, you can try asking NSURL...

```
url = [[dataSource response] URL];
filename = [[url relativePath] lastPathComponent];
if(0 == [filename length] || [filename isEqualToString:@"/"])
{
    // try getting a name that makes sense. If you have a dataSource, try this...
    filename = [dataSource pageTitle];
    if(0 == [filename length])
    {
        filename = @"index";
    }
}
filename = [filename stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"webarchive"];
```

If you want to load a webArchive, you can use WebFrame's -loadArchive: method.